# How does the GC know when to collect an object?

Tags: java, garbage-collection

I know that the GC collects objects that have no references pointing to the object in question, but what happens in the event of listener objects?

Suppose you have an `AnimationDelegate` that listens to data from a `DataSupplier`. When the `DataSupplier` recieves data and fires off the event to the `AnimationDelegate`, the delegate will then invalidate (/update/redraw etc...) a `Graphic`. Now say the screen is disabled, removed or, through various means, the graphic can no longer draw and is collected. The `AnimationDelegate` is still registered to the `DataSupplier`. How will the GC know to collect it? Should one unregister the delegate in the graphics `finalize()` method?

Comment: It uses reference counting.  Basically, whenever there are no more pointers to an object, it will be garbage collected on the next GC pass.

Comment: it actually is all implementation dependent. I do remember that some still use reference counting but I do not think that the GC which comes with HotSpot JVM does.

Comment: If you want to get technical about it, the HotSpot JVM comes with a "mark and sweep" GC algorithm.  But regardless of the algorithm, the net effect is the same.  When the GC runs, Objects which are no longer being referred to get garbage collected.  Whether these Objects with no live references are identified by reference counting, mark and sweep, or some other algorithm is largely beside the point.

Comment: Well... no. It does depend on the algorithm. As you can read from mine or other comments reference counting can have problems with circular references while tracing collectors won't have that problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm afraid the answer won't fit the format :) Start with [this article](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-jtp01274/index.html) by Brian Goetz: he's a perfect person to read if you're interested in GC.

Basically, as soon as object is *not reachable* from active threads, it's collected. The actual algorithms vary even within one JVM, but the point stays the same: what's not reachable is a garbage. What's reachable is not a garbage. Easy.

GC will not collect the `Graphic` in your example, as it's reachable from `AnimationDelegate`, which in turn is reachable (via subscription) from `DataSupplier` which is supposed to be reachable from some active thread. So the answer will be: your assumptions are wrong; GC will not collect anything here.

To answer your question, unsubscribe everything you don't need.

As @rfeak rightfully says, `finalize()` is a big no-no. It's almost impossible to use it properly, and it's way too easy to use it wrong. That said,it's OK to use it as a backup solution when you need to free resources. But generally your application *has to* be able to work just fine even if `finalize()` never gets called.

Answer (score 2):

It all depends on the JVM you're using and the GC. Most default GC from the JDK use the so called "tracing collectors", which simply start at a given **root** set of objects and trace all the objects reachable from that set. All the other objects in memory are seen as garbage and deleted. So circular references aren't really a problem unless one of the objects is reachable from the root set.

What is the root set of objects? Well if memory serves right roots can be found in: program registers, local variables in each thread's stack and static variables.

To see if your objects will be GC'd we would know more about the design of your application.

@Edit: Oh and I almost forgot: [Memory Management in the JavaHotSpot™ Virtual Machine](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/memorymanagement-whitepaper-150215.pdf). This is a pretty good overview of how it all works.

Answer (score 0):

It will only know if you have removed the references (nulled them out).

However, don't do this on finalize(). Finalize is bad bad bad. There should be other lifecycle methods available for cleaning up listener(observer) type objects.

By the way, observer pattern is notorious for creating memory leaks because the GC couldn't collect due to lingering references.

Comment: That's what I was realising (although secretly hoping I was wrong...). I'm sitting here working on my drawing stuff, and the thought occurred to me.

Comment: The first statement seems not exactly true, the java gc can handle circularity in references, while the naive model of "it will know only if you nulled them out" cannot. Assume you have a model with references inside it. Assume you have object A with a field leading to object B and vise versa. If none of them are accessable from your program, they will be garbage collected - though their references were not nulled. Though I might be missing the point of the question here :\

Comment: I wasn't commenting on the cycle detection which I know that GC can handle. I was commenting on the dangling listener problem that the OP described. A GC can NOT deal with that. The code must clean up those references explicitly, and I suggest that not be done via finalize().